# Seeking advice on proper approach to development on Netflix Eureka discoverable Spring Boot services with minimal overheads

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, netflix-feign

We are running a Spring Boot-based environment with about 15 microservices and a Zuul edge gateway registered with Eureka. Currently, I have set up all microservices to call other microservices through the Zuul gateway (e.g. if serviceA needs to call serviceB, the URL configuration property would be `serviceB.baseUrl=http://zuul.mydomain.com:7001` where zuul.mydomain.com is our development server on AWS with all other microservices running behind it). Zuul in turn proxies to the microservices via Eureka registry lookups.

One benefit of doing it this way is that for a developer working locally on his machine, he would just need to run his service and all other dependencies on other services are reachable through the Zuul gateway on AWS (and in our ecosystem, there's a lot of such cross-service dependencies).

Now, I would really love to leverage on the full potential of Eureka / Ribbon and make calls directly to a peer microservice via its service name and a `@LoadBalanced RestTemplate` but I find that this would impose quite a lot on the developer having to recreate an entire ecosystem on his machine. At a minimum, he would have to run Eureka, his own service and any other services that his service is dependent on. This makes the barriers to entry for development unnecessarily high.

I did consider making the developer's local instance register to our Eureka service on AWS, but the problem is that all services on AWS are registered using the EC2 instance's private IP which is basically unreachable from the developer's machine. If I force the service to register using its public IP, it would mean that I have to use up more of our ElasticIP allocation for each service or change the IP every time the EC2 instance gets rebooted.

I could run a local Eureka + microservices environment in the local network but that means I need to create one such environment for every office we operate out of and that just means more overheads. In addition to that problem, it would probably mean that developer A may be calling developer B's half-done-not-quite-there-yet version of a dependency service which just confuses the heck out of everyone if a problem occurs (the services that get deployed to our AWS environment at least goes through a code review first before being deployed).

If there's anybody who has figured out a way to simplify a developer's setup while being able to leverage on the peer-to-peer service invocation possibilities of `Feign / @LoadBalanced RestTemplate` clients, I would love to get some pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have confirmed that I can accomplish what I want (which is to be able to do local development on Ribbon enabled RestTemplate clients without having to run Eureka) by:

1. Force Ribbon to not use Eureka using the following property: `ribbon.eureka.enabled=false`
2. Manually provide Ribbon with the servers to point to using the following sample property: `servicename.ribbon.listOfServers=test.service.com:8080`